# Workbooks(name) Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am working in a main excel workbook where I keep all the data. I have a button that  allow the user to update the "state" of the data in progress by looking in another workbook. When clicked on it, it will open the Excel file containing the workbook, and read the column corresponding to the state of the data. If the Excel containing the workbook is already open in the same "tab", it will read the information needed, and return to the main file. If the Excel file is not open, it will open it and then close it when over. The problem I am currently facing is that if the file is open in a different "tab", I am not allowed to use the name of the Excel file to assign it as a Workbook.

```
check = IsWorkBookOpen("\\\Éclairage\Demandes\" + nomSuivi)

If check = True Then  

Set suivi = Workbooks(nomSuivi)  'nomSuivi is the name of the Excel file ex: file.xls 




    TotalRows = suivi.Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row    
    ReDim mandat(1 To TotalRows)
    ReDim etat(1 To TotalRows)

    For i = 2 To TotalRows
     mandat(i - 1) = suivi.Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(i, 1).Value   
     etat(i - 1) = suivi.Worksheets("Feuil1").Cells(i, 5).Value   
    Next i
```

Comment: Do you mean it's open in another instance of Excel? If so, this might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46140256/how-to-connect-to-open-workbook-in-another-instance-of-excel

Comment: I've come with a simple solution. Probably not the best but it does the trick for what I want to do. What I do is that if there is an error caused by the set suivi line (because the file is open in another instance), I just open the file in the same instance and then close it.