# Link Text box value from Word to Excel

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I have created a Text Box and a spin button in Word and linked them together with the following VBA code

[image]

```
Private Sub SpinButton1_Change() 
TextBox1.Text = SpinButton1.Value
End Sub
```

So When I click the spin Button the the number in text Box will increase by 1.

My Question:

How Can I  also link the value in text box to a Cell in  an existing excel file?

For example When I Click the spin button in  **WORD the  CELL  A1  IN THE EXCEL**  and also the Text box in Word increase by 1

Thank you so much

Comment: What if Excel isn't running? Should the VBA code launch it? What if two or more instances are running? What if there is no ActiveWorkbook in the Excel instance? Do you really want to write a value into *whatever the active sheet is in whatever the active workbook is in whatever Excel instance*?

Comment: Suppose I have an open excel file and want to link the value to Cell A1 in Sheet 1

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46142513/1188513) should help get you started (see [`GetObject`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/user-interface-help/getobject-function)), but as it stands your question is still very broad - as you can see in that linked Q&A, the OP there was asking a much more specific question; once you have the Excel instance with the `Workbook` object you want, you need to get the `Worksheet` you want, then the `Range` you want to write to. Feel free to [edit] your post with the specific step you're stuck at.