# How to connect to OPEN workbook in another instance of Excel SAP Issue

Tags: multiple-instances, save-as, sap-gui, excel-365

I tried to follow up with the topic here:
[How to connect to OPEN workbook in another instance of Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46140256/how-to-connect-to-open-workbook-in-another-instance-of-excel)

But I ran into a problem,
I am not able grab the new instance name or path.

However I know I have open Excel window in another instance (opened from a SAP system) and when I open VBA editor in that SAP generated Excel file and I type: `? Thisworkbook.Path` in immediate window I get nothing, no path is given and thus this solutions does not get the instance path.

What can I do to make it work ?

My issue is that this: `Set xlApp = GetObject("C:\Tmp\TestData2.xlsx")` is not grabbing the workbook name (including `This.workbook.name` or `activeworkbook.name`)

Any idea how else I can make VBA code in instance 1 work with workbook in instance 2?

I only want to save it nothing more, I'm using `Saveas` option, or at least I try.

Have anyone had a similar issue?

Comment: If your question is about SAP software, then you should describe what software it is, what you do precisely. If your question is about how to get the list of all existing Excel instances, then just ask it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with the Excel files downloaded from SAP is always problematic.

You can use the module below and add before the `xls.Close SaveChanges:=False` this line `xls.SaveAs Filename:='Any name that you want` after that just place a call in your code after downloading the Excel File with

`Call Close_SAP_Excel("TestData2.xlsx")`

And it should work fine.

Module:

```
#If VBA7 Then
  Private Declare PtrSafe Function AccessibleObjectFromWindow Lib "oleacc" ( _
    ByVal hwnd As LongPtr, ByVal dwId As Long, riid As Any, ppvObject As Object) As Long

  Private Declare PtrSafe Function FindWindowExA Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal hwndParent As LongPtr, ByVal hwndChildAfter As LongPtr, _
    ByVal lpszClass As String, ByVal lpszWindow As String) As LongPtr
#Else
  Private Declare Function AccessibleObjectFromWindow Lib "oleacc" ( _
    ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal dwId As Long, riid As Any, ppvObject As Object) As Long

  Private Declare Function FindWindowExA Lib "user32" ( _
    ByVal hwndParent As Long, ByVal hwndChildAfter As Long, _
    ByVal lpszClass As String, ByVal lpszWindow As String) As Long
#End If

Sub Close_SAP_Excel(ParamArray FileNames())
    'Procedure to close files downloaded from SAP and at the same time close the Excel application instance that will be open with them.

    Dim ExcelAppSAP As Variant
    Dim ExcelFile As Variant
    Dim FinishedLoop As Boolean, TimeoutReached As Boolean, FileClosed As Boolean
    Dim ReTry As Long
    Dim i As Long, x As Long
    
    Set ExcelAppSAP = Nothing
    ReTry = 100000 'Used as Timeout 100000 = ~10 seconds
    i = 1
    
    'The following loop is executed until excel file is closed.
    'Inside of this, there is a For Loop for each Excel Instance and inside of that is another loop
    'for each excel inside the instance. If name matches, it is closed.
    Do While Not FinishedLoop
        If i > ReTry Then
            TimeoutReached = True
            Exit Do
        End If
        
        For Each ExcelFile In GetExcelInstances() 'Function to Get Excel Open Instances
            For Each xls In ExcelFile.Workbooks
                For x = LBound(FileNames()) To UBound(FileNames())
                    If xls.Name = FileNames(x) Then
                    
                        Set ExcelAppSAP = ExcelFile 'Set Instance opened by SAP to variable
                        'Here add actions if needed. Reference to workbook as xls e.g.: xls.Sheets(1).Range("A1").Copy
                        xls.Close SaveChanges:=False
                        FileClosed = True
                    
                    End If
                Next x
            Next
        Next
        
        If FileClosed Then
            FinishedLoop = True
        End If
        i = i + 1
    Loop
    
    ThisWorkbook.Activate

    If Not TimeoutReached Then
        If FileClosed Then
            On Error Resume Next
            If ExcelAppSAP.Workbooks.Count = 0 Then
                ExcelAppSAP.Quit
            End If
        Else
            MsgBox "Excel application instance from SAP was not closed correctly. Please close it manually or try again.", , "Error"
        End If
    Else
        MsgBox "Max timeout reached", , "Error"
    End If

End Sub
     
Public Function GetExcelInstances() As Collection
  Dim guid&(0 To 3), acc As Object, hwnd, hwnd2, hwnd3
  guid(0) = &H20400
  guid(1) = &H0
  guid(2) = &HC0
  guid(3) = &H46000000

  Set GetExcelInstances = New Collection
  Do
    hwnd = FindWindowExA(0, hwnd, "XLMAIN", vbNullString)
    If hwnd = 0 Then Exit Do
    hwnd2 = FindWindowExA(hwnd, 0, "XLDESK", vbNullString)
    hwnd3 = FindWindowExA(hwnd2, 0, "EXCEL7", vbNullString)
    If AccessibleObjectFromWindow(hwnd3, &HFFFFFFF0, guid(0), acc) = 0 Then
      GetExcelInstances.Add acc.Application
    End If
  Loop
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you.
With some small tweeks it worked!
after searching for so long finaly something that works :)
However my source code as well as this1 is in  PERSONAL.xlsb, and after the code runs i have issue with read-only XLSB file.
How can i set a code so that it will be read only for any instance of excel?

Comment: Great! I am glad it worked. I did a lot of research to try to solve this issue months ago. What kind of issues are you having with the XLSB files? I didn't understand exactly the question about the read only for any instance of excel? Can you explain me a little bit more in detail?

Comment: yes, this solution works fine, however it is saved in PERSONAL.XLSB file aswell as my main macro.
After the 2 types of files are closed im left with blank grey window. when i click the window a msg box pops up saying that PERSONAL.XLSB is in  use and if i want to read only, notify or cancel, after i choose any option the windows closes.

So im thinking of there is a way to say automaticly "read-only" when  this question pops up?

Comment: Hi @AlexRivax,
Isee ur from Poland like me :)

Can you help out again?
How do I choose a SAP variant not by row number but by its proper name?

Comment: Hi @RadosławPoprawski you mean like the variant for a specific view in SAP or how?